# CSS, box around image not going away

Tags: html, css

I have a box around an image, twitter to be precise, I can not get it to go away. it looks like the following: [image] it only happens in internet explorer to my site, www.isaveplus.com , in all other browsers, it does not show up. I assumed it was text-decoration, that was not the case. the following is how it looks:

```
<div style="width:11%; float:left; background-color:#2C6B23; height: 51px; border-top-right-radius: 20px 20px; border-bottom-right-radius: 20px 20px; border-left-color:White; border-left-width:1px; border-left-style:groove; text-align:center ">
<a href="https://twitter.com/ISavePlus1" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"> <img src="picture/twitter.png" alt="twitter" style="height: 100%; width:auto; text-decoration:none;" /> </a>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how to remove that blue box around the image? Thanks!

Comment: Never mind! got it, was border-style!

Comment: Delete the question, or you'll recieve tons of -1... not from me, but there are others that like the negative vote button

Answer (score 0):

Add **border:0** for img

```
<div style="width:11%; float:left; background-color:#2C6B23; height: 51px; border-top-right-radius: 20px 20px; border-bottom-right-radius: 20px 20px; border-left-color:White; border-left-width:1px; border-left-style:groove; text-align:center ">
<a href="https://twitter.com/ISavePlus1" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"> <img src="picture/twitter.png" alt="twitter" style="height: 100%; width:auto; text-decoration:none; border:0" /> </a>
</div>
```

But better do it into externel css file, not in style attribute.

```
img{border:0;}/* reset border for all images*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **border:none** for img

```
<div style="width:11%; float:left; background-color:#2C6B23; height: 51px; border-top-right-radius: 20px 20px; border-bottom-right-radius: 20px 20px; border-left-color:White; border-left-width:1px; border-left-style:groove; text-align:center ">
<a href="https://twitter.com/ISavePlus1" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"> <img src="picture/twitter.png" alt="twitter" style="height: 100%; width:auto; text-decoration:none; border:none" /> </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `style="border:0"`